# Zeroes of derivative of Weierstrass's elliptic function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm asked to show that the Weierstrass's elliptic function $\wp: \mathbb{C}/\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ has exactly 4 branch points. My problem is that I don't see why there are 4 branch points and not just 3.

I looked at the zeroes of the derivative $\wp '$. Since $\wp '$ is doubly periodic and odd this implies that $\frac{w_1}{2}$, $\frac{w_2}{2}$ and $\frac{w_1+w_2}{2}$ are zeros of $\wp '$, where $w_1,w_2$ span $\Gamma$. But I know that an elliptic function has the same number of poles as it has zeros (where the order of the poles / zeroes matters). Since $\wp '$ has only one pole (of order 3) I know that the three zeros are all of order 1 and in particular there can't be a fourth zero.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You mean the inverse of $\wp$ (the elliptic integral)   is a function $\mathbb{C}P^1 \to \mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ with $k=4$ branch points ?

Comment: $\wp$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$, so locally around $z=0$ it is  like $1/z^2$ whose inverse $1/\sqrt{z}$ has a branch point at $z=\infty$. The 3 other branch points are the one you found where $\wp'(z) =0$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this conversation. I personally was taught that branch points live in the domain of the map, not in the codomain. It's true at the branch point lies _above_ the point at infinity of $\mathbb{CP}^1$, but we would still say that the branch point itself is the point $z = 0$ on $\mathbb C / \Gamma$.

Comment: @KennyWong $\wp$ is meromorphic  (no branch point) $\mathbb{C} / \Gamma $ to the Riemann sphere.

Comment: @user1952009 It's an unfortunate overlap of terminology. Here, "branch point" means a branch point of the branched covering of the sphere, not branch point as a singular point like for $\log z$ or $\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So it really means branch point of the inverse ?

Comment: @user1952009 Not quite, the branch points of the inverse live in the sphere, the branch points of the covering live in the torus. But they're the preimages of the branch points of the inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final branch point is at $z = 0$, and the reason for this is a bit subtle.

The image of $z = 0$ under $\wp$ is the "point at infinity" on $\mathbb {CP}^1$. In fact, $z = 0$ is the *unique* point on $\mathbb C / \Gamma$ whose image under $\wp$ is the point at infinity on $\mathbb {CP}^1$. Since the map $\mathbb C/\Gamma \to \mathbb {CP}^1$ is of degree two, this observation alone is enough for us to conclude that $z = 0$ is a branch point.

For an alternative perspective, recall that our map $\mathbb C / \Gamma \to \mathbb {CP}^1$ is given by $z  \mapsto [1 : \wp(z)] $ for $z \neq 0$. But to define the map at $z = 0$, we need to rewrite the map as $z \mapsto [\wp(z)^{-1} : 1]$. Now $\wp(z)$ has a double pole at $z = 0$, so $\wp(z)^{-1}$ has a double zero at $z = 0$, hence $z = 0$ is a branch point of our covering with ramification index equal to two.

Comment: $\wp$ is meromorphic, can you explain why we say zeros of order $2$ are branch points ?

Comment: But why doesn't this contradict the fact that $\wp '$ has only one pole of order 3, so it can only have the 3 zeroes. What confuses me even more is the fact that since $\wp '$ is odd, we have $\wp '(0)=-\wp '(0)$, so $0$ is a zero of $\wp '$.

Comment: @user450093 It's like $z \mapsto z^2$, as a covering of the sphere, it has two branch points, $0$ and $\infty$, although its derivative has only one zero.

Comment: @user450093 as a function $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ : $\wp'(z)$ is odd and has a pole at $z=0$.  as a function $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ it has a zero at $z=0$ because $\frac{1}{\wp(z)}$ has a zero of order $2$ at $z=0$

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok. So if I find a point where the derivative vanishes, I know that it is a branch point. But there may be more branch points (which make the derivative not vanish). Is this right?

Comment: @user450093 A pole of order greater than one is also a branch point.

Comment: @user450093 Actually the "derivative of the function" **does** vanish at the point $z = 0$. But given that we must write our map using a coordinate chart on $\mathbb {CP}^1$ that includes the point at infinity, the function whose derivative we care about is $\wp(z)^{-1}$, not $\wp(z)$. The statement that $\wp(z)^{-1}$ has vanishing derivative at $z = 0$ follows immediately from the fact that $\wp(z)$ has a double pole at $z = 0$.

Comment: @KennyWong: one last question... You say that since the map $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ is of degree 2, we conclude that $0$ is a branch point (since it is the only point that is mapped to $\infty\in \mathbb{C}P^1$). What is the general statement behind this? Is it something like "if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is of degree bigger than 1, then $w\in X$ is a branch point of $f$ if $w$ is the only preimage of some $z\in Y$"?

Comment: Good question! The statement is: Let $f : X \to Y$ be a surjective map between Riemann surfaces of degree $d$. Pick any $q \in Y$, and suppose $\{p_1, \dots, p_n \}$ are the preimages of $q$ under the map $f$. Let $e_{p_i}$ be the ramification index of $f$ at $p_i$. Then $\sum_{i}e_{p_i} = d$.

Comment: This "ramification index" $e_{p_i}$ is defined as follows. Suppose $w$ is a coordinate for a chart $U$ on $Y$ that includes the point $q$, and suppose $w = 0$ at $q$ itself. Consider the function $w \circ f$, which can be viewed as a holomorphic function on the open subset $f^{-1}(U)$ of $X$. Since $w$ vanishes at $q$, it's clear that $w \circ f$ vanishes at each $p_i$ in the preimage of $q$. The ramification index $e_{p_i}$ is defined to be the order of vanishing of $w \circ f$ at $p_i$. If $e_{p_i} \geq 2$ at a given $p_i$, we say that $p_i$ is a branch point of $f$.

Comment: In our example, $f$ is of degree two. So for a given $q \in Y = \mathbb {CP}^1$, there are only two possibilities: (i) $f^{-1}(q)$ consists of two points $p_1, p_2$, such that $e_{p_1} = e_{p_2} = 1$, or (ii) $f^{-1}(q)$ consists of a single point $p$, such that $e_{p} = 2$. In case (ii), the point $p$ is a branch point of $f$.